# Downgrade laravel to version 4.0

Tags: laravel, downgrade

I want to downgrade laravel to version 4.0 as i'm facing lots of issue with the current version. There is no guide on the internet. What is the procedure to downgrade laravel in ubuntu?

Comment: I guess re-install appropriate version

Comment: That's what i want to ask. How?

Comment: i recommend 4.0.9 that one was very fast and the best one. 4.1 sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

If you started with a L4.0 installation, upgraded it to L4.1, you should be able to `git cherry-pick` your commits to undo the update.

If you started with L4.1 then you should carefully examine the differences between 
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/v4.1.18 and https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/v4.0.9

Watch all the files that changed in the [upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade) and download the older files from github.

Don't forget to update your `composer.json` to have this in the `required` object:

```
"laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
```

Then run `composer update --no-scripts`.

Comment: That seems to be a complicated process. my version is 4.1.24 and i had a fresh installation of this version. Is it possible to remove current version completely and install 4.0

Comment: It is possible. It depends on which files/folders you added and in which files you have made modifications. If you used a `app\Acme` folder and didn't do too much changes in `bootstrap/start.php` and `app/filters.php` you should be fine.